# Naming convention for components doing CRUD operations

Tags: naming-conventions, crud

Let's assume I have CRUD for users. How should I name components: `UserEdit`, `UserDelete` etc or `EditUser`, `DeleteUser` etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [React Admin Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/simple?file=/src/comments/CommentList.tsx) I decided to follow the rule from the general to the specific - `UserDelete`. Besides it looks like it is easier to find files.